# Ngrok net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH errors

Tags: http, webserver, tunnel, http-error, ngrok

I'm trying to set up an ngrok tunnel to a locally run webserver serving on port 5000.  I can access the website fine over localhost:5000, but when I set up an ngrok tunnel on port 5000 I get `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` errors on all of the css and js resources in Chrome 46.0 and Safari 9.0.1.

I do not get these errors when accessing the ngrok link from Firefox 42.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and what I might do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved this issue just with adding lines bellow in devServer config. So I've changed default express timeout, turned on compression and added proxy. Maybe this will help someone...

```
keepAliveTimeout: 120000 * 5,
compress: true,
// Set this if you want to enable gzip compression for assets
proxy: {
  '**': 'http://localhost:8080'
}
```